# How wrap tag <Link> outside a <Router> with ConnectedRouter?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

i cant' switch router

#### index.js

In this project used `ConnectedRouter`

```
ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <ConnectedRouter history={history}>
      <App />
    </ConnectedRouter>
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

#### App.js

```
    <nav className="flexVCent row gutterH">
       <Link to="/" className="App-logo-wrap">
          <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
       </Link>
       <div className="flexHRight">
          <div className="flexExpand"> </div>
       </div>
   </nav>
```

How correctly wrap Link ?

package.json

```
  "dependencies": {
    ...
    "connected-react-router": "^6.2.2",
    "history": "^4.7.2",
   ...  
  },
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use 'useHistory()', the components and pages you use must be inside the router.

```
import React from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter, Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';
import Footer from '~/components/commons/Footer';
import Header from '~/components/commons/Header';
import MenuHeader from '~/components/commons/MenuHeader';
import AboutPage from '~/pages/AboutPage';
import HomePage from '~/pages/HomePage';
import ShopPage from '~/pages/ShopPage';
import NotFoundPage from '~/routes/NotFound/NotFoundPage';

const routeComponents: React.FC = (props: Props) => {
  return (
    <div className="pg">
      <BrowserRouter>
        <Header />
        <MenuHeader />
        <div className="pg__pages">
          <Switch>
            <Route path="/" exact={true} component={HomePage} />
            <Route path="/about" exact={true} component={AboutPage} />
            <Route path="/shop" exact={true} component={ShopPage} />
            <Route path="*" component={NotFoundPage} />
          </Switch>
        </div>
        <Footer />
      </BrowserRouter>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: I try to contribute as little as possible to the project code so far.
I'll try the first option first, after that yours.

Comment: `BrowserRouter` is from `react-router-dom`. He, as stated, using `connected-react-router` hence instead of `BrowserRouter` should use `ConnectedRouter `, as my post. While in general its the same - name ir `Router` and has to be at the start, its good to use what the @xersuy asked so he wouldint need to switch to new module and re-do his work elsewhere too. p.s. Here is the documentation on `conected-react-router` https://www.npmjs.com/package/connected-react-router

Answer (score 1):

`<Link>` doesnt belong inside the `<Route>`. `<Link>` is simply a URL change. Using it you change the URL. The `<Route>` is responsible for loading a differet component based on the URL.

Wrapping entire project, as you have right now, in `ConnectedRouter` will allow you to use `<Link>` and `<Route>` anywhere. You simply have to do it just once wrapping entire project at the start. But `ConnectedRouter`, or `Router` for short, IS required once at the start. Without it it wont work.

Right now it would seem to have no issues what so ever in your project. The URL changes to `/` when clicking that button with the image.

Now if you wish to load a different component with that changed URL you require to have `<Switch>` and inside of it `<Route>` to specify what component to load with what URL.

Heres a basic example of this that i found on github https://github.com/supasate/connected-react-router/tree/master/examples/basic